# Most important and Basic things about jmeter

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

I am learning Jmeter Load testing tool, Explore Jmeter with the help of doc from Jmeter community but i have some question running in my mind.

1)What is the minimum PC configuration to use Jmeter for to check load.

2)how i can start with the no. of user to test load.

3)Threads, Ramp-up and loop controller how it inputs with the test script.

4)what is the maximum capacity of the threads while we test load.

5)how i can use of the Timer for the checking of concurrent user load test.

Comment: Study the documentation properly before asking questions. You can find a lot of guides on Google for JMeter. 
If you still feel some questions are unanswered. Ask again. We will help you.
We'll be more thn happy to help you.

Comment: Yeah, i faced some problem while test load on website. error detail "Connection reset" and "Connection Refuse". so, can you please Elaborate why error coming.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no, different applications can hold different load. The
   better the application hardware and software, the more power you
   need to load it.
2. You click the Run button.
3. 100 users 1000 seconds ramp up means you will introduce a new user every 10 sec.
4. Maximum capacity is the maximum number that your hardware can
   handle.
5. Jmeter has a lot of listeners, you can pick the one you
   think has the most information.

Comment: Thank you for do needful answer.